# Выполняет ли браузер JavaScript скрипты если они в теге с css свойством display:none;

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Прячу так некоторые счётчики. Вот думаю будут ли они выполняться если так спрятаны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да. Будут работать. А смысл его прятать? **Javascript** и так не отображается на странице. Он всегда по умолчанию спрятан, от глаз пользователя.

Comment: да javascript счётчики посещаемости такие как LiveInternet показывают свои назойливые кнопки с цифрами для бесплатных аккаунтов и скрыть нельзя.

Comment: это производные работы скрипта, а не сам скрипт

Comment: У этого блока с рекламкой, должно быть свое **id**, **class** - Вам надо ему присваивать **display: none;**  
Или написать **JS** и ловить его.

Comment: "производное скрипта" появляется именно в месте скрипта, во всяком случае я себе так всегда счётчики настраиваю. Проще же просто весь код скрипта в скрытый блок положить и всё, что бы его производные не засоряли страницу. В общем проверил через alert, действительно код отлично работает в скрытом блоке. Принципе иначе быть и не могло ведь css отвечает только за отображение.